# How to get data from other sheet using date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have 
sheet1,

```
Name    Date    Amount
Ali     1-Sep   50
Ali     2-Sep   100
Ali     5-Sep   30
        13-Sep  40
        9-Aug   50
        25-Sep  60
```

and sheet2,

```
Name    Date    Amount
Ali     1-Sep   100
Ali     2-Sep   100
Ali     5-Sep   85
Ali     13-Sep  34
Ali     9-Aug   88
Ali     25-Sep  25
```

on sheet 3, how do i search both sheet1 and sheet2 using dates, get the amount from both sheets and sum both amount on sheet3

output :

```
Nama    Tarikh  Total
Ali     1-Sep   150
Ali     2-Sep   200
        3-Sep   
        4-Sep   
        5-Sep   115
        6-Sep   
        7-Sep   
        8-Sep   
        9-Sep   138
        10-Sep  
        11-Sep  
        12-Sep  
        13-Sep  74
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `VLOOKUP` function to get the total.  Enter the following formula into cell `C2` in Sheet3:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet1!$B$2:$C$7, 2, 0) + VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!$B$2:$C$7, 2, 0), 0)
```

[image]

This assumes that your data in sheets 1 and 2 are structured as follows:

```
    A       B         C
1 Name  |  Date  |  Amount
2  Ali  |  1-Sep |    50
3  Ali  |  2-Sep |   100
4  Ali  |  5-Sep |    30
5       | 13-Sep |    40
6       |  9-Aug |    50
7       | 25-Sep |    60
```

Comment: do i need to do the formula manually on each row? because when i drag the C2 on sheet3, there are errors.

Comment: @hafizyBaharudin I updated my answer with a correct formula, my apologies for not testing thorougly enough.

Comment: what if the are multiple value with the same date? how do i add the value? coz right now the formula u gave just took 1 value, not sum it all up ..TQ

Comment: @hafizyBaharudin You are changing the requirements of your original question.  It would be best if you open a new question, and maybe cite this one or just start using the accepted answer here.

Comment: i see...ok will do..tq for the help mr TimBiegeleisen

Comment: i have already open a new question for this.. please take a look mr tim
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584546/adding-value-from-same-using-from-multiple-sheets

Answer (score 0):

You can use *=Sheet1!A1* and *=Sheet2!A1* on Sheet3.

In general: use "=[SheetName]![CellName].

To see this easier: type '=' in the required ceel in sheet3 and click another sheet to chose the required cell. Excel will do the job for you

Comment: this didn't work because on sheet1 and sheet2, the dates are not sorted..