# Adding Value from same using from multiple sheets

Tags: excel

on further response from my [1st question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264219/how-to-get-data-from-other-sheet-using-date) , i would like to ask how do i add up the values i got from the sheet if there are multiple same dates. e.g

```
Name    Date    Amount
Ali     1-Sep   50
Ali     2-Sep   100
Ali     5-Sep   30
        13-Sep  40
        13-Sep  70
```

in the solution @timbiegeleisen gave, only the 1st value are taken, the 2nd value is ignored. I want to add all the value from the choosen date.

Thank you

Comment: Does the name have any effect on what you are looking for or is it unrelated?

Comment: the name is unrelated, i only need to add the amount if the dates are the same

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!DateRng,Date,Sheet1!AmtRng)+SUMIF(Sheet2!DateRng,Date,Sheet2!AmtRng)
```

For example:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7,Sheet3!B2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7)+
 SUMIF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$7,Sheet3!B2,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$7)
```

assuming your data is set up similarly to the question you linked.